# WP7 How can I simplify this code or any better approach?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Is there any way to simplify this code? Or any way to create another page of class page to keep the main page clean as possible. I’m planning to have hundreds of text file and since I’m a newbie I don’t the best way to approach this. I’m trying to make an app with Xbox 360 achievement guides, but each game averaged around 40 achievements. (That’s allot of text files).

```
if (selectedIndex == "0")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = "Story Complete [MEDIUM]\n" + Environment.NewLine + sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Feel The Payne";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "1")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = "Story Complete [HARD]\n" + Environment.NewLine + sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Serious Payne";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "2")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = "Story Complete [OLD SCHOOL]\n" + Environment.NewLine + sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Maximum Payne";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "3")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/TextFile1.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Payne In The Ass";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "4")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Part I Complete";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "5")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Part II Complete";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "6")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Part III Complete";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "7")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/TextFile2.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "A New York Minute";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "8")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/TextFile3.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "The Shadows Rushed Me";
        AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}
else if (selectedIndex == "9")
{
    var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/TextFile4.txt", UriKind.Relative));

    using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
        Guide.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        Title.Text = "Out The Window";
        YouTubeLink.URL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRg6ygA-M_Y";
    }
}
```

I would love to have this text files somewhere in the internet as the user can retrieve them as needed.

Comment: You may want to consider posting this at:
http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Might get some additional suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. If you really want to bundle all your data with the application, you could [serialize it to XML](http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/11/windows-phone-7-serialization-xmlserializer/) or [JSON](http://mobile.dzone.com/news/windows-phone-7-serialization-1?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20zones/dotnet%20%28.NET%20Zone%29) and then deserialize it internally.

This also adds flexibility to your code, since working directly with hardcoded values like you do might cause some headaches in the long run, when you decide to add changes.

Comment: I would love to have a json file in the net, but don't where and how to retrieve to my app.

Comment: You could host it anywhere (there are plenty of choices) and then you could use something like WebClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.95).aspx) to get it.

Answer (score 0):

ist only a example with anonymous struct, you can also extend this with xml + linq

```
var actions = new[]
{
 new {
  index = 0, 
  uri = "Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt", 
  guide = "Story Complete [MEDIUM]\n\n", 
  title = "Feel The Payne", 
  appBar = false, 
  youtube = ""
 },

 new {
  index = 7, 
  uri = "Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/TextFile2.txt", 
  guide = "", 
  title = "A New York Minute", 
  appBar = false, 
  youtube = ""
 },

 new {
  index = 9, 
  uri = "Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/TextFile4.txt", 
  guide = "", 
  title = "Out The Window", 
  appBar = true, 
  youtube = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRg6ygA-M_Y"
 },
};

var actionQuery = actions.Where(a => a.index == selectedIndex).ToArray();

if (actionQuery.Length == 0) throw new Exception("Index not found: " + selectedIndex);
if (actionQuery.Length > 1) throw new Exception("Duplicate entries found: " + selectedIndex);

var action = actionQuery[0];

var Tutorial = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(action.uri, UriKind.Relative));

using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
{
 StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
 Guide.Text = action.guide + sr.ReadToEnd();
 Title.Text = action.title;
 AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = action.appBar;
 if (action.youtube != "") YouTubeLink.URL = action.youtube;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should populate the ListBox (i'm guessing it's a ListBox) with actual classes

```
public class Tutorial
{
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Prefix { get; set; }
}
```

With this class, populate the ListBox with these classes. It would be best to have this list in an xml/json format or even better grab from the web.

```
List<Tutorial> tutorials = new List<Tutorial()
{
    new Tutorial 
    { 
        Location = "Resources/Games/MaxPayne3/StoryRelated.txt",
        Title = "Feel the Payne",
        Prefix = "Story Complete [MEDIUM]\n"
    }
    // add more
};
ListBox.ItemsSource = tutorials; // better to do binding to this property
```

Then in the selectionchanged event

```
Tutorial tutorial = ListBox.SelectedItem as Tutorial;
if(tutorial == null) return;

var item = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(tutorial.Location, UriKind.Relative));

using (Stream Text = Tutorial.Stream)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Text);
    Guide.Text = tutorial.Prefix + sr.ReadToEnd();
    Title.Text = tutorial.Tile;
    AppBarMenuDisable.IsEnabled = false;
}
```